# bucket Terms aggregation Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

**elasticsearch version**

```
{
  "name" : "abc-Inspiron-5521",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "2vLvphpURJOtfAZSGDDX5w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "747e1cc71def077253878a59143c1f785afa92b9",
    "build_date" : "2021-01-13T00:42:12.435326Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**Document mapping**

```
"user_data" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
         "experience" : {
          "properties" : {
            "brand" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "brand_segment" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "company" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "duration" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "property_type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "real_estate_type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Document structure is right, please make changes if there is mismatch in parenthesis accordingly.

**document sample**

```
{
        "_index" : "user_data",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "dONuEXgBU9vYaZRqY8Jo",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "experience" : [
            {
              "brand" : "Hilton",
              "company" : "Hilton LLC",
              "brand_segment" : "Luxury",
              "property_type" : "All-Inclusive",
              "duration" : "2 years",
              "real_estate_type" : "Institutional"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "Mantis",
              "company" : "Accor LLC",
              "brand_segment" : "Upper-Upscale",
              "property_type" : "Condo",
              "duration" : "2 years",
              "real_estate_type" : "Family Office"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "Marriott",
              "company" : "Marriott LLC",
              "brand_segment" : "Independent",
              "property_type" : "Convention",
              "duration" : "2 years",
              "real_estate_type" : "Family Office"
            }
          ]
        }
}
```

**my term aggregation query on brand_segment**

```
GET user_data/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    
      "experience": {
        "terms": { "field": "experience.brand_segment" }
      }
    }
}
```

Now I have 2 problems while making term aggregation

1. While executing term aggregation on 'brand_segment', the value 'Upper-Upscale' is suppose to be considered as single unit and count is to be made according but currently I am getting it as:
2. Second concern is if I want to count number of times brand_segment value is 'Luxury' or any value, but currently from above query I am getting count of number of documents in which Luxury occurs, not the number of times in all documents Luxury occurs. (multiple occurrences are getting counted as single for 1 document as of now).

**wrong result**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "experience" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "independent",
          "doc_count" : 15
        },
        {
          "key" : "luxury",
          "doc_count" : 15
        },
        {
          "key" : "upper",
          "doc_count" : 14
        },
        {
          "key" : "upscale",
          "doc_count" : 14
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Desired output should have Upper-Upscale as one value. I have taken multiple sample documents hence this result.

**feel free to use this as sample document for creating index**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "abcs",
  "source": "csv_status",
  "profile_complition": "70%",
  "creation_date": "2020-04-02",
  "current_position": [
    {
      "position": "Financial Reporting",
      "position_category": "Finance",
      "position_level": 2
    }
  ],
  "seeking_position": [
    {
      "position": "Financial Planning and Analysis",
      "position_category": "Finance",
      "position_level": 3
    }
  ],
  "last_updation_date": "2021-02-02",
  "experience": [
    {
      "brand": "Hilton",
      "company": "Hilton LLC",
      "brand_segment": "Luxury",
      "property_type": "All-Inclusive",
      "duration": "2 years",
      "real_estate_type": "Institutional"
    },
    {
      "brand": "Accor",
      "company": "Accor LLC",
      "brand_segment": "Luxury",
      "property_type": "Condo",
      "duration": "2 years",
      "real_estate_type": "Family Office"
    },
    {
      "brand": "Marriott",
      "company": "Marriott LLC",
      "brand_segment": "Independent",
      "property_type": "Convention",
      "duration": "2 years",
      "real_estate_type": "Family Office"
    }
  ]
}
```

other occurrences in brand_segment = ['Economy', 'Upscale', 'Midscale', 'Upper-Upscale', 'Luxury', 'Independent', 'Extended Stay']

PS: all brand_segment are desired to be considered as single entity ('Upper-Upscale' is not desired as 'Upper', 'Upscale'. Same for 'Extended Stay')

Let me know if further clarification required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first issue, you need to make your aggregation on the `keyword` subfield:

```
GET user_data/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    
      "experience": {
        "terms": { "field": "experience.brand_segment.keyword" }
      }
    }
}
```

To solve the second issue, you need to make your `experience` field [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), which means your mapping needs to look as follows:

```
"user_data" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
         "experience" : {
          "type": "nested",                 <--- add this
          "properties" : {
            "brand" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, your suggestion worked for me.
Can you help me with how to make already indexed document nested. Or the above document nested while indexing directly from kibana. Currently I am using "POST /user_data1/_doc/" followed by sample document I mentioned above to index data. As you have figured out I am new to es.

Comment: You cannot change already indexed documents, but you can reindex them with the adequate mapping

Comment: Can you explain with example on above document?

Comment: I understand the type nested is to be added, my concern is how. I tried modifying it with below code lines-
PUT user_data/_mapping/
{
      "properties": {
        "experience": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
  }
But its showing bad request, error code 400. Can you please let me know how are you making it nested both before indexing the document and after it.

Comment: As I said, you cannot modify the mapping to nested after the index has been created. You need to create a new index and reindex your data into that new index with the new mapping

Comment: Following your suggestion, I made new index doing the following:
"experience" : {
        "properties" : {
          "type": "nested",
          "brand" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
            "fielddata" : true,
and then indexing few documents successfully. But still experience field is not nested, when I am seeing my doc structure via "GET /user_data1" . In short making field nested is still how to do for me.

Comment: Ok, let's not pollute this thread any more. The question has been answered, so feel free to create another thread with an exact recreation of what you're currently trying to do